# Como activar email en Heroku for Devise para resetear password

Tags: devise

Hola alguien tiene experiencia parametrizando rails para el ambiente produccion (heroku)? Estoy tratando de enviar mails con Devise para resetear el password de los usuarios cuando es requerido. Encontre un articulo que sugiere el cambio de 2 parametros:

```
- config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://your-app-on-heroku.herokuapp.com' }
- config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'
```

Hice los cambios en mi aplicacion Rails pero sigue enviando el mail al log como en el ambiente de test:

```
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949473+00:00 app[web.1]: From: tractionapp@gmail.com
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949475+00:00 app[web.1]: Reply-To: tractionapp@gmail.com
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949476+00:00 app[web.1]: To: laura.s.chavez@outlook.com
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949478+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <5bc0ae5fe73bd_42ab51090f82c627c4@57555215-feb3-43fd-aaa7-b57dc06720ed.mail>
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949479+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Reset password instructions
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949481+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949482+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949484+00:00 app[web.1]: charset=UTF-8
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949485+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949486+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949487+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Hello laura.s.chavez@outlook.com!</p>
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949488+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949490+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949491+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949493+00:00 app[web.1]: <p><a href="http://harm-reduction-tracker.herokuapp.com//users/password/edit?reset_password_token=EtsN8sP4orWeUsr3bnjM">Change my password</a></p>
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949494+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949495+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
2018-10-12T14:23:27.949497+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```